# My threads don't appear on Keil uvision's RTOS watch

Tags: arm, keil, cortex-m, rtos, rtx

I'm using Keil uVision with RTX5 RTOS and for some reason I can't see the threads I'm creating in the RTOS watch... I can only see the built in RTX idle thread and timer thread...

I've tested that my threads run with a breakpoint.

[image: RTOS watch showing only RTX built in threads]

[image: My code using "task_1" and "task_2"]

Comment: Post _code_ not  _pictures of code_.

Comment: You are using a weird mix of mbed and RTX APIs  What version of mbed?  In mbed RTOS, `main()` runs in a thread context and the kernel is already initialised and started before `main()` runs.

Comment: The executable lines (darker grey shading in the debugger gutter) do not align with the code - that is the code that is running is not the code that is displayed.  In particular, the `main()` function appears  to have far less code in it than the text.  I suspect your code is out of date and needs re-building.  Either way, it is enough to indicate that you are not telling us everything or giving accurate information.